# Amazon S3 Bucket Index?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, bucket

Hello i want to use my bucket to display a index or a redirect is that possible?

For example when i go to my bucket bucket1example.s3.amazonaws.com,
i get AccessDenied error

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>42RP9K65G8T9EA7A</RequestId>
<HostId>
byYoD3naIjOi3aqwONTrAkOL2Basfdj29faPMz29sgofukHo15K987GIRClOuscJmzKX0S24EzM=
</HostId>
</Error>
```

But if i go to my file doc.html bucket1example.s3.amazonaws.com/doc.html i can see my file.
Is there a way to display the Doc.html file with the url "bucket1example.s3.amazonaws.com"?
Is possible when i visit bucket1example.s3.amazonaws.com automatically redirect to "doc.html"?

Answer (score 3):

You have to enable static website hosting for the bucket and configure an index document

This AWS document can help you with the configuration.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/IndexDocumentSupport.html

Comment: Hello Subhashis Pandey, i already haave the static website and the doc.html configured, but only works with the url with region ej. my.bucket.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com

But i want to work with the simple s3.amazonaws.com url

Comment: Your original question was different, must use Route53 for custom URL